# Rails 5: undefined method `instantiate_observers' for ActiveResource::Base:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activeresource

I created a rails 5 project and I'm trying to import a gem I made. I get the following error when i run any rake tasks from the rails project:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `instantiate_observers' for ActiveResource::Base:Class
```

The error is coming from the gem as the project runs fine when i comment it out in the Gemfile. Seeing as instantiate_observers isn't called anywhere in the gem, I've narrowed the error source to be coming from this line:

```
    class BaseResource < ActiveResource::Base
```

Obviously I need it to inherit from ActiveResource, so I can't figure out a solution. Also, the rails-observers gem is in the gem's gemfile:

```
activeresource (4.1.0)
  activemodel (~> 4.0)
  activesupport (~> 4.0)
  rails-observers (~> 0.1.2)
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm having the same issue using the master branch. Any leads or workarounds?

Comment: I submitted a ticket (https://github.com/rails/activeresource/issues/221) which was promptly closed along with this commit - https://github.com/rails/activeresource/commit/6c4c02b77ea04060b02bf023d93fd0e076756427.

So it seems it was just some lingering code.

Comment: Nice looks like that works for me also. Thanks for doing that!